# Merge two tables based on Join - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

My 1st table

```
select * 
from dbo.tblusertasks

   id   pagename              search    _update     _delete   _insert
    1   CustomerMaster          0          0           0         0
    2   OrganizationMaseter     0          0           0         0
    3   Vendor/SupplierMaster   0          0           0         0
```

My 2nd Table

```
select * 
from dbo.tblpages

id  pagenameid  userid  createdby   search  _update _delete _insert
1   1             1        1          1        1       1       1
2   2             1        1          1        1       1       1
```

I want to merge these two  and need the result as

```
id  pagename               search   _update _delete _insert
1   CustomerMaster           1         1       1      1
2   OrganizationMaseter      1         1       1      1
3   Vendor/SupplierMaster    0         0       0      0
```

I have tried this query but its not working

```
SELECT  
    pg.id, pg.[pagename], tblp.[search],tblp.[_update] , 
    tblp.[_delete], tblp.[_insert] 
FROM 
    tblpages pg 
LEFT JOIN 
    [tblusertasks] tblp ON tblp.pagename = pg.id 
WHERE
    tblp.userid = 1
```

It's returning (I tried both left and right join but its still returning the same):

```
id  pagename            search  _update _delete _insert
1   CustomerMaster         1       1       1      1
2   OrganizationMaseter    1       1       1      1
```

Comment: remove where condition tblp.userid=1

Comment: Shouldn't the on part be "on tblp.id=pg.id"? Pagename contains strings and pg.id numbers. There is probably the problem...

Answer (score 0):

SIcne you said you have tried both the LEFT and RIGHT JOIN and it isn't working changing the tables arounf wouldn't help. YOu will need to do this:

```
SELECT pg.id,
       pg.[pagename],
       tblp.[search],
       tblp.[_update],
       tblp.[_delete],
       tblp.[_insert]
FROM [tblusertask] tblp
     LEFT JOIN tblpages pg
        ON tblp.ID = pg.pagenameid
```

This should work.

Comment: i tried it but when i add a where condition its not returning the desired output

Comment: With the set in your post you shouldn't need a where clause.

Comment: Its for future use like when i have multiple users then Ex userid 2, 3 etc

Comment: As long as the users are in one table and not in another table the join will return that. This join currently pullback everything in tblusertask and only values that match in tblusertask from tblpages.

Comment: i have to put the userid in the same table as it is working like a foreign key

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...
This gives you the flexibility to partition by PageName... count, sum etc..

```
SELECT pagename,
    T.pagenameid,
    ISNULL(T.search, 0) AS search,
    ISNULL(T._update, 0) AS _update,
    ISNULL(T._delete, 0) AS _delete,
    ISNULL(T._insert,0) AS _insert
FROM
(
SELECT 
    MAX(U.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY pagename) AS pagenameid,
    MAX(U.search) OVER (PARTITION BY pagename) AS search,
    MAX(U._update)  OVER (PARTITION BY pagename) AS _update,
    MAX(U._delete)  OVER (PARTITION BY pagename) AS _delete,
    MAX(U._insert)  OVER (PARTITION BY pagename) AS _insert
FROM 
    tblusertasks U
LEFT JOIN   
    tblpages P ON U.id=P.pagenameid
)T
INNER JOIN tblusertasks UT ON UT.id=T.pagenameid
```

RESULT

[image]

Comment: @AkhilRJ This is exactly matches your desired output as you wanted...
Can you explain what's missing ?

Comment: The columns search ,update , delete and insert are of bit type , so MAX() is invalid for it